# Como recuperar os valores de um formulário em HTML para uma função em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma página com um formulário feito com Bootstrap e precisaria recuperar os dados submetidos para um arquivo javascript externo ao HTML.

Meu principal objetivo seria recuperar o campo de senha para fazer validações através da função `ValidarSenha()`.

Agradeço toda a atenção desde já.

Segue o código HTML

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
                <form name="cadastro" class="form-set" action="/pagina-destino" onsubmit="return ValidaSenha()" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="ex: João da Silva"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="ex: joaodasilva@dominio.com.br"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="csenha">Confirme sua senha</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="csenha" name="csenha"/>
                    </div>  
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Enviar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Não ficou muito claro o que está exatamente a tentar fazer. Em que local precisa de usar os dados ? De que forma os quer usar ? Qual a localização do arquivo onde quer usar ? Esse arquivo é JS ou PHP ?

Answer (score 1):

Para pegar os dados de um `<input>` você pode usar o `id` dele e pegar no JavaScript usando a função `document.getElementById('senha_input').value`.

[Resposta com outras opções](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)